# Link to open Code in a new window or copy to clipboard option

Tags: feature-request, code

When you hover over code on a question or answer, it would be nice to in addition to the syntax highlighting to maybe show a link in the top right corner or something you can click on that will open a small window with just that code in it so you can copy and paste the code very easily.  Or else a link/button to copy the contents to a clipboard, I believe this can be accomplished with Flash.  I have seen these features on most blogs and sites that have syntax highlighting.

Comment: this would be nice, especially since, at least from my experience, if you highlight and copy code it all gets put on one line.

Comment: +1: This would be really useful. It is troublesome trying to copy stuff when trying to troubleshoot/try code in a question. Anything that reduces the boring bits of answering a problem is great

Answer (score 1):

They could add a colored line, like they do in SuperUser quotes, that could be clicked on to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the perfect application for greasemonkey...

Answer (score 1):

[Syntax highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) does it but it has quite a big overhead when loading. [The google alternative](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is a lot faster but has no new window feature.

SO already has syntax highlighting though so just a new window icon would be useful, and fairly easy to add.